# Programs to find, show, edit and save lyrics in Linux

Tags: audio, music, music-recognition

I am using Linux and Windows in multiple-boot. When I go to Linux I start missing some programs to find, edit and **(especially) save** lyrics like the ones I use in Windows: Foobar2000 (with Lyrics Show Panel) and MiniLyrics.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Are there similar programs in Linux?